# How to get the same behavior as CSS rule `display: inline-block` in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget

I would like to put in a container (a widget) a list of children widgets that would have a fixed size. I would like the children to use the entire available width (if possible) and to start a new row when the previous row has been completely filled.

I would like to do something similar to the CSS property `display: inline-block` in C++ with Qt.

The excepted result is a table :

[image: Cells]

I am using Qt 5.10 and I am working on a C++ project (not a QML project)

Is there a way to do that ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create your own *QLayout* to do this.

A good starting point is the **Flow layout example**. You can find it in the official documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html).